# JSON value undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{"a":"111","b":"7"}
```

Also, I have a selectbox with value (a and b). I want to make it when user select "a", it will show "111" from the JSON while select "b", it will show "7".

I wrote the following jQuery, but the JSON value returned out is undefined.

```
<select id="selectbox" name="selectbox">
            <option value="a" grouping="">A</option>
            <option value="b" grouping="">B</option>
</select>
```

The field store the JSON value:

```
<input id="JSON" name="JSON" type="text" value="{"SickLeave":"111","AnnualLeave":"7"}">
```

My jQuery code:

```
$("select[name=selectbox]").on('change', function() {

      var obj = JSON.parse($('[name$=JSON]').val());
      var optionvalue = $("select[name=selectbox] option:selected").val();

      console.log(optionvalue);
      console.log(obj.optionvalue);
});
```

However, the "obj.optionvalue" is undefined.

Comment: Hint: look at the quotes in the `value` attribute where you put the JSON..

Comment: You don't have a property on your `obj` named `optionvalue`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable for solutions to that problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can help:
First you have to replace `{"SickLeave": "111", "AnnualLeave": "7"}` by `{"a": "111", "b": "7"}` which has the structure of the JSON you used in the javascript code. Also as mentioned by @Rory McCrossan in his comment it was necessary to differentiate brakets that wrap up the value and those used in the json as follows: `value='{"a":"111","b":"7"}'`
Since optionvalue is a variable, the most correct way to access the value of the attribute of the json having le value of optionvalue as key is to do the following:`obj[optionvalue]` instead of `obj.optionvalue`

```
<select id="selectbox" name="selectbox">
  <option value="a" grouping="">A</option>
  <option value="b" grouping="">B</option>
</select>
<input id="JSON" name="JSON" type="text" value='{"a":"111","b":"7"}'>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
    $("select[name=selectbox]").on('change', function() {

      var obj = JSON.parse($('[name$=JSON]').val());
      var optionvalue = $("select[name=selectbox] option:selected").val();

      console.log(optionvalue,obj);
      console.log(obj[optionvalue]);
   });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's always best to *explain* your answers rather than merely providing code - otherwise the OP doesn't know what you're showing them.

Comment: Thank you @Utkanos, for your comment, I added a few more details to my answer.